# How to prevent CMake from putting the release version in the .so filename?

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, filenames, symlink, dynamic-library

I build a dynamic library (.so file) with CMake.  With the pretty standard settings

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(mylib PROPERTIES SOVERSION "1" VERSION "0.3.1")
```

CMake creates the following files in /usr/lib:

```
libmylib.so -> libmylib.so.1
libmylib.so.1 -> libmylib.so.0.3.1
libmylib.so.0.3.1
```

where -> indicates a symlink.  Well, this may make sense if the SOVERSION matches the major version of the release, but I learned that there is no need to synchronize both (and it would be very awkward for our project).

What I would expect is:

```
libmylib.so -> libmylib.so.1
libmylib.so.1
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Remove `VERSION "0.3.1"` part?

Comment: Accordings to CMake's documentation, CMake then assumes the release version to be the same as the .so version, however, they differ in our case.